# Não consigo marcar a opção 'Assinalar os manifestos ClickOnce'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly

Tenho um projeto do Visual Studio em que preciso assinar o assembly desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para o projeto Phoenix_painel (exemplo do print acima) marcar esse item é opcional. Mas para que o projeto Phoenix_communication obrigatoriamente tenho que fazer isso.

A cada copilação obtenho este erro no projeto Phoenix_communication:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Descrição da mensagem de erro:

> Gravidade Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
>   Erro        Não é possível registrar o assembly "C:\Users\thiag\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Trabalho\Arco\Software Do Arco\Phoenix_communication\Phoenix_communication\bin\Debug\Phoenix_communication.dll"; acesso negado. Verifique se você está executando o aplicativo como administrador. O acesso à chave do Registro 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Record' foi negado.    Phoenix_communication

Se a cada copilação eu criar um novo arquivo de chave de nome forte consigo copilar o programa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que isso faz com que o trabalho fique muito lento. Segundo meu chefe o problema poderia ser resolvido ao ativar a opção Assinalar os manifestos ClickOnce e selecionar o arquivo .pfx correspondente ao arquivo de chave de nome forte selecionado. Mas como não consigo selecionar está opção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não é possível selecionar essa opção. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Execute o Visual Studio como administrador.Clique com botão direito(disposição de botões padrão) no ícone do Visual Studio na barra de tarefas, dentro do menu que surgir clique como o  botão direito no atalho do Visual Studio abrirá um submenu onde você escolherá Executar como Administrador.

Comment: Apesar de não ter feito isso quando tirei os prints, executo sim o projeto como administrador e tenho o erro descrito. Testei novamente para conferir e apresentou o mesmo problema.

Comment: Estive lendo sobre seu problema e encontrei isso: [(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/.../hkeyclassesrootname-of-the-class-is-denied](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00c1306f-096b-497f-8b51-a5174f5c7ac2/access-to-the-registry-key-hkeyclassesrootname-of-the-class-is-denied?forum=csharpgeneral) diz que sua conta não possui privilégios para modificar essa chave. Experimente logar como ADM da máquina, alguém certamente vai me criticar por conta da segurança, ou em modo de segurança e tente fazer a operação.

Comment: isso não faz muito sentido uma vez que sou capaz de realizar esse processo no outro projeto dessa mesma solução. E Meu usuário é administrador.

Comment: Só uma ideia abra o editor de registros e de uma olhada nessas chave `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies` e `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`, veja se tem algum policy restringindo a edição específica de algum registro `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Comment: Não há nada na pasta HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies

Comment: Achei isso aqui: [https://www.codeproject.com/../How-to-Sign-ClickOnce](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1225324/How-to-Sign-ClickOnce-Deployment-if-ClickOnce-Code). Ele explica que Os arquivos do aplicativo, o manifesto da aplicação, o manivesto de publicação e o boostrapper devem estarem assinados e individualmente.